Can I boost my Terminator armour "Force Field" roll with a Fate point?
The Terminator armour in Deathwatch has a special ability that works similar to a force field (Deathwatch Core Rule Book p. 164):

[...] the Crux Terminatus on every Terminator’s shoulder plate serves as a ward capable of turning aside attacks from power weapons, melta fire, and even the baleful energies of the warp. This protection provides the same chance to emerge unscathed as a Force Field (see page 166) with a Protection Rating of 35. Since this is purely due to the chance of the hit glancing off the armour’s strongest surfaces, there is no possibility of Overload.

When looking at the rules for using Fate points, the options include:


Re-roll a failed test once. The results of the re-roll are final.
Gain a +10 bonus to a test. This must be chosen before dice are rolled.
Add an extra Degree of Success to a test. This may be chosen after dice are rolled.


Re-rolling the failed test would apply, simply enough, but the better options of guarantee would be the other two. My only hesitance is simply because it's a pass/fail roll - degrees of success don't apply.

You can add 10 before the roll, which gives you a 45% chance of passing.
Re-rolling gives you a 57.75% chance of passing. Doing both gives you a 69.75% chance of passing, but uses 2 Fate points if the first roll fails.
Degrees of Success only apply when the roll says that they do. Even if you could add a Degree of Success to a failed Test, it is still a failed Test.
